# select all value with single string when have multiple values for search result of `isin` from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

Select **all values** with **one string** when have **multiple values** of search result using `isin` from pandas dataframe, this example result should be `"'40','50','60','70','80'"`

**python code**

```
d = [['b', '1', 40],
    ['b', '2', 50],
    ['b', '3', 60],
    ['b', '4', 70],
    ['b', '5,6', 80]]

p = pd.DataFrame(d)
p.columns = ['one', 'two', 'three']
p.loc[p['one'].isin(["b"])]['three']
```

**Execution Result**

```
    one two three
0   b   1   40
1   b   2   50
2   b   3   60
3   b   4   70
4   b   5,6 80
```

**expected result**

```
 p.loc[p['one'].isin(["b"])]['three'][*]
 
"'40','50','60','70','80'"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
# get the numbers to a list
numlist = p.loc[p['one'].isin(["b"])]['three'].tolist()

# concatenate the list to get the desired format
",".join(f"'{num}'" for num in numlist)
```

Output:

```
"'40','50','60','70','80'"
```

Comment: dear, what is the meaning of f"'{num}'" ? can you explain more ?

Comment: He's converting `num` to string form and adds single quote chars for each `num`.